# Compatability of Macbook Air with HP 23fi

Tags: macbook-pro, airplay, mirroring

Is HP Pavilion 23fi monitor compatible with Macbook Air?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by compatible? Do you mind an adapter or do you mean compatible directly without the need for a cable conversion?

Answer (score 1):

The HP Pavillion 23fi monitor has the following inputs:

- 1 VGA
- 1 DVI-D
- 1 HDMI

Because Macbook Air has only Thunderbolt output (or Mini DisplayPort for previous models) you need an adapter to use it with this monitor.